# Best way to display tabular data with sorting feature in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a sqlite database. I want to display it on tabular form and when clicked on the header of the table column it should sort the data accordingly. What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Attached is the format i want to implement on android app. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: share your `code` till now

Comment: i have not started it. I just want to start with right technologies. You know someone said 'Do not reinvent the wheel'.

Comment: You should be trying out `TableLayout`

Comment: @Navneet: Thanks for the reply. What about GridView?